# Make tooltip appear on corresponding points in different ggplot2 facets in a plotly object

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-plotly

I am using `ggplot2` and the `plotly` R packages to generate a volcano plot to visualize protein differential abundance data.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

nVals <- 80
nFacets <- 2

#example dataset
proteins <- rep(paste0('protein_', c(1:(nVals / nFacets))), nFacets)
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(log_FC = c(rnorm(nVals*0.8, 0, 1), rnorm(nVals*0.2, 0, 12)),
                  log_Pval = abs(rnorm(nVals, mean=0, sd=0.01)),
                  facet = rep(paste0('Cell line ', 1:nFacets), nVals / nFacets),
                  protein = proteins[order(proteins)])


#make ggplot2 object
p <- ggplot(dat, aes(y = log_Pval, x = log_FC, text = protein)) +
  facet_wrap(~ facet) +
  geom_point()

#convert p to plotly object with plotly::ggplotly
ggplotly(p)
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDPVo.jpg) of current output

I am using the tooltip feature in `plotly` to show the data associated with each point. I would like to extend the tooltip feature to highlight the same protein in different facets of the plot.

In other words, **when a cursor hovers over a point in 1 facet, the tooltip box would show up on all points which have the same value in the** `dat$protein` **column in adjacent facets.**

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlkVT.png) is an example of what I am aiming for.

Is there some way of the customizing the behavior of the tooltip to achieve the what I have described?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `crosstalk`, you can have widgets communicate with each other. Create a `SharedData` object from your data frame, and select `protein` as the key.

```
library(crosstalk)
shared_df <- SharedData$new(dat, key = ~protein)
```

Then, use `shared_df` instead of `dat` with `ggplot`. If you select a point in one plot, it will highlight the matching data point (by `protein`) in the second plot. Please let me know if this meets your needs.

Comment: This defiantly solves the problem and allows me to compare points between facets. I'd really like the tooltip to show up on the other point though. However, after doing some more research I don't think that is possible without using javascript.

Comment: Anyone figure out how to get the tooltip to show up on the other point?